# How to override color on illustrations/icons that can't be flattened in Sketch App?

Tags: svg, icon, sketch-app, technique

I'm trying to create a styleguide according to atomic design. For this I'm trying to create a set of icons where I can override the color so I can use them in different sets.

I made an icon of a plane using shapes and strokes:

[image]

Normally I can use a mask to override the color on the icon. But I can't use folders as masks. When I try to union/flatten this icon, things go wrong:

[image]

Is there a way to fix my icon or a way around this so I can still use a mask for the override?

Answer (score 1):

**You can fix your icon and mask it with color symbol.**

Follow these steps to create simple line illustration to mask with color symbols:

1. Draw illustration elements using vectors with empty fill property and **thick borders** (10) with color (orange)
   [image]
2. After you complete drawing all elements using vector, **combine all illustration elements** to single combined shape. I used Union to combine shapes in the given example. Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C89OYYnjqFA) to learn more about boolean operations in Sketch.
   [image]
3. Select the combined shape and **convert to outlines** (Layer => Convert to outlines). Convert to outlines will convert lines to solid shape filled with color instead of border.
4. Now you can **mask the icon** with color symbols.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I drew all my icons using vector shapes in Sketch though... They all have empty fill and thick borders. If you draw for example a rectangle with a circle in it, with no fill and thick border, and union these, the middle shape will disappear.

Comment: Now I understood your problem. One simple hack is to leave one pixel gap between two shapes while combining using union.